# Disable mini apps tray on galaxy tab?

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I'm trying to disable the mini app tray in samsung tab 2, but as for now i hav no luck with tat.
  I'm running a service in in the background of my app to return the package name of the app running on top of the stack,and even that service is not able to catch if an app is run from the mini app tray ,
but once i maximize that app then my service catches that app's package name.

Is there a way to capture the touch of mini app tray ? or is there any possibility to disable the mini app tray form system bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process proc = null;
    OutputStreamWriter osw = null;
    proc = runtime.exec("su");
    osw = new OutputStreamWriter(proc.getOutputStream());
    String cmd="mount -o remount rw /system

    String miniapp = "mv /system/framework/minimode.jar /system/framework/modeminix.jar";

    osw.write(miniapp+"\n");}catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
```

This removes the mini app tray on reboot of the device (ROOT - needed)